# Output of linear model in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I am learning R for statistical analysis. Earlier, also I've fitted some linear models and they worked well. But this time I am getting a weird problem. For data set in file "Auto.csv", I am trying to run a simple linear model to predict mpg for one predictor horsepower by running the code

```
auto=read.csv("Auto.csv")
summary(lm(mpg~horsepower, data = auto))
```

I am getting an output like:

```
Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
 -9.050 -2.183  0.000  1.778 14.533 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    2.900e+01  1.814e+00  15.989  < 2e-16 ***
horsepower100 -9.406e+00  2.063e+00  -4.559 7.48e-06 ***
horsepower102 -9.000e+00  4.443e+00  -2.026 0.043663 *  
horsepower103 -8.700e+00  4.443e+00  -1.958 0.051117 .  
horsepower105 -8.500e+00  2.159e+00  -3.937 0.000102 ***
................................................

horsepower98  -8.750e+00  3.393e+00  -2.579 0.010389 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.056 on 303 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7945,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7314 
F-statistic:  12.6 on 93 and 303 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I am expecting an output like:

```
Residuals:
      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
 -13.5710  -3.2592  -0.3435   2.7630  16.9240 
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 39.935861   0.717499   55.66   <2e-16 ***
 horsepower  -0.157845   0.006446  -24.49   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
 Residual standard error: 4.906 on 390 degrees of freedom
 Multiple R-squared:  0.6059, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6049 
F-statistic: 599.7 on 1 and 390 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

It might be a silly question, but I am stuck at it (I am new to programming). Please help.

Comment: Check the format of your variable `horsepower`. It looks like it is treated by R as a factor. You can either add the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when using `read.csv()` or convert your model so that it reads `summary(mpg~as.numeric(as.character(horsepower)), data = auto))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the horsepower variable, you can see that it is read as a factor variable since there are some "?" in the data. You can convert it to numeric with the following code:

`auto$horsepower <- as.numeric(levels(auto$horsepower))[auto$horsepower]`

Then run the regression again:

`summary(lm(mpg~horsepower, data = auto))`

You can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information) if you want to understand that conversion.

Comment: Thanks @Regis, it worked. But I am wondering, why R is considering "horsepower" as factor? I've also tried 'auto = na.omit(auto)', before running the linear model. Still it takes the variable as factor.

Comment: Since there is a string "?" in the variable, R should recognize it either as type character or factor (strings are not automatically converted as NAs, and they shouldn't). R recognized it as a factor because there is repeated values (more than one "?" and probably cars with the same horsepower). So it seems to R that this is a categorical variable.

Answer (score 0):

A problem with

```
 auto=read.csv("Auto.csv")
```

You should read table as numeric and be careful with separator:

```
 myDataFrame <- read.csv("path/to/file.csv", header=TRUE, sep=delim, dec=dec, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

(from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706188/importing-csv-file-into-r-numeric-values-read-as-characters))